# Missing URL(from: NSPasteboard) and Swift 3

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3

I have the following function:

```
override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        let pasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        let fileURL = URL(from: pasteboard)
        // Does something
 }
```

I am getting the following error at "URL(from: pasteboard)"

> Argument labels '(from:)' do not match any available overloads

From what I can tell NSURL has the following method.

```
init?(from pasteBoard: NSPasteboard)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is URL is not the same as NSURL.  The changes to Swift 3 didn't just remove the NS, to make things easier to read, but implemented there own simplistic version of NSURL.  When on an Apple device it will secretly use NSURL.

To fix it I changed my code to use this:

```
let fileURL = NSURL(from: pasteboard) as? URL
```

More information about the removal of `NS` can be found here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md

If you want to view the source code it is found here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/URL.swift